# Spring Security default /login endpoint returns 404 "No static resource login."

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I've been pulling my hair out for hours on this one.
I'm setting up my Spring Security. I've created a `CustomerAuthenticationProvider`, an `AuthenticationFilter`, a `JWTGeneratorFilter`, and a `JWTValidatorFilter`. When I make a POSTMAN request to `localhost:8080/login` I get the following response:

```
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "detail": "No static resource login.",
    "instance": "/login"
}
```

With this warning output:

```
DEBUG 81686 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /login
WARN 81510 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource login.]
```

The Content-Type is set to application/json. I'm putting in correct login details in valid raw JSON format. I don't have any controller method for "/login" or anything similar.

EDIT: If I make a request to /login with an incorrect username or password, I get the expected HTTPStatus code and custom exception messages returned. The 404 problem only appears when using valid credentials.

I have commented out as much as possible in my `SecurityConfiguration` to try and find the problem, leaving only the `AuthenticationFilter` (when I leave the JWTGeneratorFilter in, it goes through the whole process correctly, creating the JWT token, etc, but I get the exact same 404 result):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(customAuthenticationProvider);
//        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");

//        CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
//        requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");

        http
//            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
//                    .ignoringRequestMatchers("/register", "/confirm-account", "/login")
//                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
//            .addFilterBefore(new ExceptionHandlerFilter(), AuthenticationFilter.class)
//            .addFilterBefore(new JWTValidatorFilter(), AuthenticationFilter.class)
//            .addFilter(authenticationFilter)
            .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(customAuthenticationProvider))
//            .addFilterAfter(new JWTGeneratorFilter(), AuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeRequest) -> authorizeRequest
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/register").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/confirm-account").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

I've tried setting different paths in .setFilterProcessesUrl() to no avail.

When running it in debug mode, authentication is successful and it reaches the very last line in `succcessfulAuthentication` with `authenticated=true`. The SecurityContextHolder is filled out. I have put logs in both the `authenticate()` and `successfulAuthentication()` methods and they both register the correct username.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter { 

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);
    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class); 
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    user.getUsername().toLowerCase(),
                    user.getPassword()); 
            LOGGER.info("Attempting authentication for user: {}", authentication.getName());
            return customAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("User input fields do not match up with User class. Error message: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new InputMismatchException(User.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        LOGGER.info("Authentication successful for user: {}", authResult.getName());
        LOGGER.info("Request state: {}", request.getRequestURI());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response); // Continue to the JWTGeneratorFilter.
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                              HttpServletResponse response,
                                              AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getWriter().write(failed.getMessage());
        response.getWriter().flush(); // Forces any buffered data to be written out immediately.
    }
}
```

With LOG results:

```
INFO 81510 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.h.h.s.filter.AuthenticationFilter      : Attempting authentication for user: testuser
INFO 81510 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.h.h.s.filter.AuthenticationFilter      : Authentication successful for user: testuser
INFO 81510 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.h.h.s.filter.AuthenticationFilter      : Request state: /login
```

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());
        CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = (CustomUserDetails) userDetails;

        if (!customUserDetails.isEnabled()) {
            throw new DisabledException("User account is deactivated");
        }
        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(authentication.getCredentials().toString(), customUserDetails.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Username or password incorrect");
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                customUserDetails.getUsername(),
                customUserDetails.getPassword(),
                customUserDetails.getAuthorities()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

There are no settings relating to logins in `application.properties`.
I'm using Spring Boot 3.2.2 and Spring Security 6.2.1.

EDIT: I get the same error message when I visit `http://localhost:8080/actuator/httptrace`:

```
{
    "type":"about:blank",
    "title":"Not Found",
    "status":404,
    "detail":"No static resource actuator/httptrace.",
    "instance":"/actuator/httptrace"
}
```

Here's the first part of the `logging.level.root=DEBUG` result:

```
2024-02-07T22:33:59.120-05:00 DEBUG 82091 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Before fill(): parsingHeader: [true], parsingRequestLine: [true], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position(): [0], byteBuffer.limit(): [0], end: [0]
2024-02-07T22:33:59.123-05:00 DEBUG 82091 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@5e3490a7:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@71a93097:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:54465]], Read from buffer: [0]
2024-02-07T22:33:59.125-05:00 DEBUG 82091 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@5e3490a7:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@71a93097:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:54465]], Read direct from socket: [345]
2024-02-07T22:33:59.125-05:00 DEBUG 82091 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [POST /login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 963d5ddf-1748-4d7b-bc17-74b0aa2ab2aa
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 61

{
    "username": "testUser",
    "password": "Password123"
}]
2024-02-07T22:33:59.130-05:00 DEBUG 82091 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Before fill(): parsingHeader: [true], parsingRequestLine: [true], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position(): [0], byteBuffer.limit(): [0], end: [0]
2024-02-07T22:33:59.130-05:00 DEBUG 82091 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@6fb843fc:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@5c3b28ff:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8080 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:54464]], Read from buffer: [0]
2024-02-07T22:33:59.131-05:00 DEBUG 82091 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.io.EOFException: null
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1296) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1184) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:785) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

2024-02-07T22:33:59.181-05:00 DEBUG 82091 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request

java.io.EOFException: null
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1296) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1184) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:785) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:264) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar:10.1.18]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
```

We can see that when it reaches the `HeadWriterFilter.class` that the response contains the JWT cookie, the request shows that it was made to `/login`.

```
headerWriterResponse = {HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterResponse@14161} 
 request = {StrictHttpFirewall$StrictFirewalledRequest@14183} "FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@e9578ed]"
 this$0 = {HeaderWriterFilter@14184} 
 disableOnCommitted = true
 contentLength = 0
 contentWritten = 112
 response = {DisableEncodeUrlFilter$DisableEncodeUrlResponseWrapper@15971} 
  response = {FirewalledResponse@15973} 
   response = {ResponseFacade@15974} 
    response = {Response@14917} 
     coyoteResponse = {Response@15975} 
     outputBuffer = {OutputBuffer@15976} 
     outputStream = {CoyoteOutputStream@15977} 
     writer = null
     appCommitted = true
     included = false
     isCharacterEncodingSet = false
     usingOutputStream = true
     usingWriter = false
     urlEncoder = {UEncoder@15978} 
     redirectURLCC = {CharChunk@15979} "null"
     cookies = {ArrayList@15980}  size = 1
      0 = {Cookie@15982} 
       name = "JWT"
       value = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJobXN0Iiwic3ViIjoiSldUIFRva2VuIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0dXNlciIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjoiUk9MRV9VU0VSX0JBU0lDIiwiaWF0IjoxNzA3NDEwNTUyLCJleHAiOjE3MDc0MTQxNTJ9.G6jZJpJA20HWXmRTPkOyrP-iD1y0jfRoV-GRbjdOkA0"
       attributes = {TreeMap@15985}  size = 4
     applicationResponse = {ResponseFacade@15974} 
     request = {Request@14901} 
     facade = {ResponseFacade@15974} 
headerWriterRequest = {HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@14160} 
 response = {HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterResponse@14161} 
 request = {StrictHttpFirewall$StrictFirewalledRequest@14183} "FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@e9578ed]"
  this$0 = {StrictHttpFirewall@14186} 
  request = {RequestFacade@14187} 
   request = {Request@14901} 
    coyoteRequest = {Request@14902} "R( /login)"
     serverPort = 8080
     serverNameMB = {MessageBytes@19601} "localhost"
     remotePort = 0
     localPort = 0
     schemeMB = {MessageBytes@19602} "http"
     methodMB = {MessageBytes@19603} "POST"
     uriMB = {MessageBytes@19604} "/login"
     decodedUriMB = {MessageBytes@19605} "/login"
     queryMB = {MessageBytes@19606} "null"
     protoMB = {MessageBytes@19607} "HTTP/1.1"
     requestId = "1"
     remoteAddrMB = {MessageBytes@19609} "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
     peerAddrMB = {MessageBytes@19610} "null"
     localNameMB = {MessageBytes@19611} "null"
     remoteHostMB = {MessageBytes@19612} "null"
     localAddrMB = {MessageBytes@19613} "null"
     headers = {MimeHeaders@19614} "=== MimeHeaders ===\ncontent-type = application/json\nuser-agent = PostmanRuntime/7.36.1\naccept = */*\ncache-control = no-cache\npostman-token = 52d406a8-f407-4b1f-aebc-a267f525db7f\nhost = localhost:8080\naccept-encoding = gzip, deflate, br\nconnection = keep-alive\ncontent-length = 61\n"
     trailerFields = {HashMap@19615}  size = 0
     pathParameters = {HashMap@19616}  size = 0
     notes = {Object[32]@19617} 
     inputBuffer = {Http11InputBuffer@19618} 
     urlDecoder = {UDecoder@19619} 
     contentLength = 61
     contentTypeMB = {MessageBytes@19620} "application/json"
     charset = {UTF_8@19621} "UTF-8"
     characterEncoding = "UTF-8"
     expectation = false
     serverCookies = {ServerCookies@19623} 
     parameters = {Parameters@19624} ""
     remoteUser = {MessageBytes@19625} "null"
     remoteUserNeedsAuthorization = false
     authType = {MessageBytes@19626} "null"
```

It maintains these values throughout the filter process (I'm going through step by step with the debugger) and the first time these values don't appear is in Http11Processor.class. In this class is the first time I see something wrong:

```
this.response = {Response@15975} 
 status = 404
 message = null
 headers = {MimeHeaders@20196} "=== MimeHeaders ===\nSet-Cookie = JWT=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJobXN0Iiwic3ViIjoiSldUIFRva2VuIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0dXNlciIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjoiUk9MRV9VU0VSX0JBU0lDIiwiaWF0IjoxNzA3NDEwNTUyLCJleHAiOjE3MDc0MTQxNTJ9.G6jZJpJA20HWXmRTPkOyrP-iD1y0jfRoV-GRbjdOkA0; Max-Age=3600; Expires=Thu, 08 Feb 2024 17:43:35 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly\nVary = Origin\nVary = Access-Control-Request-Method\nVary = Access-Control-Request-Headers\nX-Content-Type-Options = nosniff\nX-XSS-Protection = 0\nCache-Control = no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate\nPragma = no-cache\nExpires = 0\nX-Frame-Options = DENY\nContent-Type = application/problem+json\nTransfer-Encoding = chunked\nDate = Thu, 08 Feb 2024 16:44:02 GMT\nKeep-Alive = timeout=60\nConnection = keep-alive\n"
 trailerFieldsSupplier = null
 outputBuffer = {Http11OutputBuffer@20197} 
 notes = {Object[32]@20198} 
 committed = true
 hook = {Http11Processor@19628} 
 contentType = "application/problem+json"
 contentLanguage = null
 charset = null
 characterEncoding = null
 contentLength = -1
 locale = {Locale@20200} "en_GB"
 contentWritten = 112
 commitTimeNanos = 1523834502372811
 errorException = null
 errorState = {AtomicInteger@20201} "0"
 req = {Request@14902} "R( /login)"
 listener = null
 fireListener = false
 registeredForWrite = false
 nonBlockingStateLock = {Object@20202}
```

Yet in the "this" part we can see the following, which indicates status of 200:

```
this = {Http11Processor@19628} 
 protocol = {Http11NioProtocol@20253} 
 inputBuffer = {Http11InputBuffer@19618} 
 outputBuffer = {Http11OutputBuffer@20197} 
 httpParser = {HttpParser@20257} 
 pluggableFilterIndex = 4
 keepAlive = true
 openSocket = true
 readComplete = true
 http11 = true
 http09 = false
 contentDelimitation = true
 upgradeToken = null
 sendfileData = null
 hostNameC = {char[14]@20258} [l, o, c, a, l, h, o, s, t, , , , , ]
 adapter = {CoyoteAdapter@20192} 
 asyncStateMachine = {AsyncStateMachine@20259} 
 asyncTimeout = -1
 asyncTimeoutGeneration = 0
 request = {Request@14902} "R( null)"
 response = {Response@15975} 
  status = 200
  message = null
  headers = {MimeHeaders@20196} "=== MimeHeaders ===\n"
  trailerFieldsSupplier = null
  outputBuffer = {Http11OutputBuffer@20197} 
  notes = {Object[32]@20198} 
  committed = false
  hook = {Http11Processor@19628} 
  contentType = null
  contentLanguage = null
  charset = null
  characterEncoding = null
  contentLength = -1
  locale = {Locale@20200} "en_GB"
  contentWritten = 0
  commitTimeNanos = -1
  errorException = null
  errorState = {AtomicInteger@20201} "0"
  req = {Request@14902} "R( null)"
  listener = null
  fireListener = false
  registeredForWrite = false
  nonBlockingStateLock = {Object@20202}
```

Comment: handing out JWT tokens straight to browsers is called an _implicit flow_ and is insecure and is deprecated and should not be implemented anymore, there has been an active choice by spring security to not include this type of authentication, hence you need to write all this custom strange code,  so i would like to know the reason for building an unsecure authentication?

Comment: Hi Toerktumlare, I wasn't aware of this. When I previously set up Spring Security (which was mid-last year) I remember reading to avoid storing JWTs locally and instead to use HTTP-only cookies. I don't actually know what the alternative is so I'll investigate it today and edit my answer once I've figured out how not to hand the token straight to the browser. After a quick google I should note I'm not using OAuth2/OIDC or access tokens. I don't know if that helps

Comment: you might think you are not using OAuth2/OIDC but sufficient to say is that your user case falls into the user specification as you are building your service to be both a resource service (providing rest endpoints to access data) and an authentication service/issuer that is authenticating users and issuing JWTs to the calling client. So you are sort of building a bad version of it. The easiest way is to avoid using JWTs and just implement FormLogin there are several tutorials and official docs on it, which is cookie based login.

Comment: Understood. I'm going to revamp my process but it's just frustrating that with my current setup [following the debug variables] the user is authenticated properly , the JWT tokens are generated correctly and assigned to the cookie correctly, yet at some stage I'm getting this error returned that I've never seen before and that I can't find anywhere else online.

Comment: Also, if for example I enter incorrect user details when trying to log in via POSTMAN, it correctly returns 401  with my custom "Username or password incorrect" exception message

Comment: I haven't been able to figure this out so I'm going to redo my security implementing (intentionally) OAuth2 w/ PKCE